# ScrollView exceeding bounds of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Udacity's course [*Developing Android Apps with Kotlin*](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012), the Layouts section, offers roughly this for `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name_text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/star_description"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio_text"
            style="@style/NameStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:text="@string/bio" />
    </ScrollView>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

The goal is to show a name, a star below it, and a scrollable description below that. When the text is short enough to fit without scrolling, this is the appearance:

[image]

But when the text is long enough to require scrolling, the scrollable area seems to move other components out of view:

[image]

The course is a little old, so perhaps some things have changed, or perhaps I applied things incorrectly. What needs to be changed so the ScrollView stays within its bounds?

Comment: If I am not getting wrong then, you are saying that name and image are also scrolling along with scrollable content, is it?

Comment: @Bhavnik it doesn't seem that it's scrolling - the name doesn't appear at all when scrolling the text up and down. The star doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/linear#:%7E:text=Layout%20Weight,-LinearLayout%20also%20supports&text=This%20attribute%20assigns%20an%20%22importance,space%20in%20the%20parent%20view.) documentation, the attribute `layout_weight` with any value greater than used for other components can be used to cause an element to use all remaining space. This `git diff` shows the change needed for the ScrollView to display correctly:

```
         style="@style/NameStyle"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
+        android:layout_weight="0"
         android:text="@string/name_text" />
 
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/star_image"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
+        android:layout_weight="0"
         android:contentDescription="@string/star_description"
         app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
         tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />
@@ -26,7 +28,8 @@
     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
-        android:layout_height="match_parent">
+        android:layout_height="match_parent"
+        android:layout_weight="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

- 

```
Copy and paste this
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding">
        
           
        
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
       < RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                style="@style/NameStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/name_text" />
        
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/star_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/star_description"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bio_text"
                    style="@style/NameStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:text="@string/bio" />
    </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

- 

Comment: Adding the RelativeLayout didn't change anything.

Comment: I did that first, fixed the typo, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this layout, may be you'll find it as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:text="Your name here" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/star_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
                android:text="set your text here" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Don, try the above-implemented code, hope this is what you're looking for.